# How to create a django project in ubuntu

Tags: django

I'm following a tutorial on Django and I'm suppose to create a folder in Ubuntu in terminal

```
$ django-admin startproject mysite
```

This above line shows

> "Cannot find installed version of python-django or python3-django."

After installing all the required stuffs.

Comment: How did you install the stuff?

Answer (score 2):

The recommended way of starting a django project in Ubuntu is using a virtualenv so first install it.

Then run

```
virtualenv -p python3 env
```

This will create an env named folder. Active the virtualenv by running

```
source ./env/bin/activate
```

Then install django with pip. now django will be installed in activated virtualenv

```
pip install django
```

and then create your project

```
django-admin startproject mysite
```